# PHP handled MYSQL process questions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an invoicing process that creates 5 tables and fills with with appropriate data, then builds a 6th final table off of those 5.  It is about 14 queries, I am thinking of using PHP to handle them due to some date variable needing to be changed.

If I put all 14 in sequence and run it, it works flawlessly. Would you want to just have the whole sequence in one statement in php? Example below:

```
$TheWholeShow = whole sql sequence
$date=$_POST["date"]
mysqli_query($connect,$TheWholeShow)
```

Or would you want to break it up?

```
$part1 = build table x
$part2 = build table y
$part... the rest
$date=$_POST["date"]
mysqli_query($connect,$part1,$part2,$part3,$part4..and so on)
```

I feel this is a hard question to ask without typing a book. Also, I am a new coder, and am unsure of the proper practices for such.

I have been told a bash script may be a better option?

Comment: You'll have to break it up. The underlying mysql drivers in PHP do NOT allow multiple queries to be executed in a single query() call.

Comment: In order to preserve integrity, use `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;`/`ROLLBACK;`. This way you can split the queries (as you are forced to do by the underlying drivers which don't allow for multiple queries, as stated by @Marc B)

Comment: If you wish, you could create a stored procedure to do this - depending on your version of MySQL.

Comment: @MarcB, There's [mysqli_multi_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) but it is not recommended to use this [for security reasons](http://xkcd.com/327)!

Comment: @bill: all that does is fire up multiple connections anyways. mysqli can't alter a fundamental restriction in the underlying drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, indeed, a tricky one.

Firstly, it's usually a bad idea to execute long-running processes in the context of a web request. Most servers impose a timeout on the script - it's a configuration value, and your mileage will vary. As your data grows, you may end up hitting that timeout, and your process will fail.

Secondly, you need to make sure only one instance of the PHP script can run at one time - especially if it's a long-running script. There's no obvious way of doing that "out of the box" that I'm aware of, so you may have to build a custom mechanism to only allow a single instance to run; this is probably harder than it sounds.

As for your question, as TheWolf writes, consider using transactions in this - not all installations of MySQL allow this. Using a transaction means that your entire database show either succeeds or fails as a unit - so no "we got so far, and then it barfed, and now we have some data but not other bits and we have to write a custom clean-up script" craziness.

As the drivers don't allow you to exectute more than one statement at a time, you'll have to split it up - but not as you suggest.

```
$date=$_POST["date"]
mysqli_begin_transaction($connect)

$part1 = build table x
mysqli_query($connect,$part1)

$part2 = build table y
mysqli_query($connect,$part2)
$part... the rest
mysqli_query($connect,$part...)

mysqli_commit($connection)
```

You'll have to build your own rollback logic - that is mostly dependent on the application logic, and how you want to handle failures in the script - the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php) has some further explanation.